# What changes are needed to maintain balance if all classes use the same XP table in BX D&D/OSR?

Tags: osr, dnd-bx

What balance problems are created by house-ruling B/X D&D (or derivatives) such that all classes advance at the same rate (i.e. they all use the fighter's XP-level table)? What fixes can be implemented to address these issues?

From looking at the charts, it looks like the Thief might suffer a bit, and the magic user might get a little bit stronger, but I'd like to hear from people who have actually done it, and figured out what fixes are best. My intiution says that giving the Thief d6 hit dice and slightly better skill chances would be the only fix necessary, but please tell me if I am wrong.

I should note that I'm not using demihuman classes, just the core 4 human classes.

My goals for implementing this house rule are twofold:

- I don't like the "feel" of the rules as written. I'm used to later editions of D&D where everyone is expected to be more or less at the same level. I admit this isn't a great reason.
- I want the ability to bypass XP and level the group up according to story milestones without changing the inter-class balance. I won't always do this of course, but for some plots, I like the approach.

Comment: Which experience table are you planning to use? If you aren't sure, I'd recommend using the fighter table, because it has the simplest progression. The other classes' tables all have places where advancement speeds up a bit, presumably because this was felt to be necessary for balance reasons.

Comment: Good recommendation. I've updated the question to indicate that I'd use the fighter table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically none.

The number of times that the difference in the experience tables matters is pretty minimal assuming all the characters are always adventuring together.  Every once in a while, a character will be one level ahead of his compatriots, but never more than that.

Just do it. But yes, using the Fighter table seems like the best idea.

Comment: There really isn't any balance to begin with.